# Change Button Class with Javascript of sorts

Tags: javascript, button

So, I am trying to change the class for a input box using javascript and can't seem to get it right.

I have 2 CSS classes.

The normal class is
.butz
and the one I want the button to change to when its clicked is
.butzz

So, I have this for my html:

```
<input id="butval1" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="" />
```

and this is my js

```
document.getElementById("butval1").className += "butzz";
```

What I really want to do, is change the class from butz to butzz
or... if possible, change the background color of my button with getElementByClassName

I have 9 buttons that are all in the same class, and I want the one clicked, to change to green or #24f000

thank you all

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akwZf/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<input id="butval1" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="changeID(this);" />
<input id="butval2" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="changeID(this);" />
<input id="butval3" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="changeID(this);" />

function changeID(elm){
    var NAME = elm;
    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if (currentClass == "butz") { 
        NAME.className = "butzz";   
    } else {
        NAME.className = "butz";  
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gGykX/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

using `javascript` you can change the class name using

```
document.getElementById('butval1').className = 'butzz'
```

if you want to add a new class by javascript use

```
document.getElementById('butval1').className += ' butzz'
```

for change clicked DOM class you need to create function and pass that clicked DOM into function as argument and using that passed args you can do this.

**Example**

```
<input id="butval1" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="changeID(this);" />
<input id="butval2" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="changeID(this);" />
<input id="butval3" class="butz" type="button" name="design1" value="Choose Design" onclick="changeID(this);" />

function changeID(args)
{
    args.className = 'butzz'
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akwZf/4/)